Implementing IntoIterator for custom collection
I am going through a tutorial on how to implement IntoIterator for a custom collection, like the implementation for &HashMap. I have a query.
Why do we implement it for &T, and not T?
User may want to call into_iter on collection directly, isn't?

Because you can't get a T from a &HashMap<_, T> without further restricting T. Did you miss that you're looking at the implementation for &HashMap (a shared reference) not the implementation for HashMap (a value)

Sorry for confusion. By T in my post, I meant collection(HashMap here). So in line I pointed to, its &HashMap. But as you pointed out, there is another implementation for HashMap too.

As you noticed, there are both implementations: one for T and the other for &T. They serve different purposes, the former gives out owned values (and is allowed to deconstruct the hashmap as it progresses), and the other gives out references (and must keep the hashmap intact). Both are useful in different situations, and the latter is by convention usually exposed through a method called iter().
